# Visual Studio: Equivalent of Eclipse's variable movement?

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, ide

Developing Java with Eclipse, it's easy to move variables from one class to another, and have the references be updated. (So if you move `size` from being a class variable to a class named `Constants`, every reference to `size` in the original class will be replaced by `Constants.size` automatically.)

Is there a way to do this in C# XNA Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Re: why this refactoring is not C#-y. I suspect you know this but static containers for values are generally a bad idea. Take your example of a Constants class, you probably have values in there like Size, AdminUserName, LogfileName - all values that are used in completely different contexts, so why are they in the same class? Before you know it you've built up a dependency between all your classes and Constants. It would be better to inject these values through the constructor or at least define them in the classes that actually use them (or a base class).

Answer (score 0):

The Devexpress RefactorPro! plugin has similar refactorings (though not I don't think that exact one).  I *think* they're even all available in the free version.  If you want a specific one that's not available though you can check the free DxCore plugins page or develop one yourself.  It's not all that hard.

All the links are on the [DxCore community plugins page](http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/).

Oh but, to answer your question very specifically no, I have never heard of that exact refactoring being available anywhere - it's not generally seen as CSharp-y.

Comment: Can you explain why it's not C#-y? I'm new to the language but have plenty of experience with Java.

Answer (score 0):

Move variable is not one of the refactoring operations that is supported by C# out of the box in Visual Studio 2010 (or 2008 / 2005 for that matter).  In order to get that kind of operation you will need to use a 3rd party plugin such as Resharper or DevExpress`s RefactorPro.